# Putting a calendar spread as a limit order

Tags: options, limit-order, option-strategies

If I want to put on a calendar spread as a limit order at interactive brokers, am I allowed to specify a limit price for the spread, or do I need to specify limit prices for each of the individual legs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about IB, but in general, and in my experience with Schwab, that's exactly how you'd enter such orders.

Bid/Ask spreads can be pretty crazy, you often see a strike showing Bid $2/ Ask $3 or a similar B/A. If the other leg of the trade is $1/$2, you might get filled as high as $2 or as low as $1. Best to enter a limit price to 'split the difference' on the spreads. If it doesn't fill as you hope you can inch up the price.

Comment: Thanks. So if I put on the spread all at once, then I can specify a limit price for the spread. But if I put one leg at a time, I need to specify limit price for each leg. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I'd highly recommend one spread limit price.